# Why does registering to event with empty lambda function cause strong reference in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, events, memory-leaks, lambda

There is some sample code:

```
public class Publisher
    event Published()
end class

public class Subscriber
    public sub new(Publisher as Publisher)
        addhandler Publisher.Published,
            sub()

            end sub
    end sub
end class
```

1. Does registering to the `Publisher` event in `Subscriber` constructor prevent `Subscriber` from being garbage collected even if an empty lambda function, that doesn't capture `Subscriber`, is passed as event handler?
2. Is it the same in C#?

**Edit**

A simple console application to test it:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Publisher As New Publisher

    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Dim Subscriber As New Subscriber(Publisher)
    Next

    GC.Collect()
    Dim TotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

    Trace.WriteLine(TotalMemory)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, *the application consumes 36 megabytes of memory after garbage collection*, which means that *all Subscribers stay in memory*!

Debug and Release on different target frameworks 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 give the same results.

3. Can anyone reproduce the issue or explain why adding an event handler works with way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't reference anything related to Subscriber in your anonymous function, it will be compiled as static method of Subscriber class and as such it won't prevent any instances of Subscriber class to be garbage collected. You may want to look at this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/02/686456.aspx - for more info.

UPDATED. Code below shows almost the same values of total memory, when running in Release mode (in Debug mode it indeed works as you said):

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        var pub = new Publisher();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            var sub = new Subscriber(pub);
        }
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Publisher {
    public EventHandler Published;
}

public class Subscriber {
    public Subscriber(Publisher pub) {
        pub.Published += delegate { };
    }        
}
```

Comment: You're correct, although I think (not 100% certain) that the caching of the anon function as a static is an implementation detail rather than specified behaviour. (Having said that, it's such an obvious optimisation to make that I'd be surprised if there were any implementations that didn't do it.)

Comment: Even if an empty anonymous function is compiled as static method, is it true that `AddHandler` (`+=` in C#) operator doesn't capture a `Subscriber` instance?

Comment: You are right. I was testing `Debug` / `Release` but _with Debugging_, I should have tested `Release` _without Debugging_ to see that `Subscribers` are really collected. It seems that `Debugger` somehow interferes.